# How to add id's to ember SelectOption

Tags: javascript, ember.js, html-select, ember-select

Is there any way to add id's to each option from the content object? I have tried

```
{{ view Ember.Select contentBinding="names" optionValuePath="content.value" 
   optionLabelPath="content.label" optionIdPath="content.identity" }}
```

This doesn't work, so I attempted to reopen `Ember.SelectOption` and investigate some possibilities.

```
{{ view Ember.Select contentBinding="names" optionValuePath="content.value" 
   optionLabelPath="content.label" indentityBinding="content.identity" }}
```

and

```
Ember.SelectOption.reopen({
    init: function() {
      this._super();
      log( this.get('identity') ); // undefined [note]
      log( this.get('content')  ); // Object{}
    }
});
```

`[note]:` The value isn't undefined, it's the property full stop.

Any suggestions? The idea is that each option will get their own id according to path provided...

I know this is quite dumb to even bother doing this, but apparently a client needs it for testing with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Really in your template you are working at the select level

```
Ember.Select.reopen({
    init: function() {
      this._super();
      console.log( this.get('identity') ); // undefined [note]
      console.log( this.get('content')  ); // Object{}
    }
});
```

and identity isn't an ember name, so you would just do

```
{{ view Ember.Select contentBinding="names" optionValuePath="content.value" 
  optionLabelPath="content.label" identity="content.identity" }}
```

And you have identity spelled incorrectly.